# SQL Server errors with foreign key conflict

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have this code here:

```
create database shop11
use shop11

create table mathang
(
       MatHangID  INT primary key not null,
       TenMatHang varchar(50),
       SoLuong    int not null,
       Price      int not null,
)

create table nhacungcap
(
       MatHangID  INT foreign key references mathang,
       TenNhaCungCap varchar(50) ,
       DiaChi        varchar(100),
       SoDienThoai   int ,
       CONSTRAINT pk_M_CC primary key (MatHangID)
)

create table khachhang
(
       KhachHangID   int not null primary key,
       TenKhachHang  varchar(50)  not null,
       [DiaChi]      varchar(100) not null,
       [SoDienThoai] varchar(50)  not null,
)

create table donhang
(
       DonHangID int references khachhang(KhachHangID),
       TenDonHang    varchar(50),
       SoLuong       int,
       CONSTRAINT pk_DHID primary key (DonHangID)
)

INSERT INTO khachhang 
VALUES ('1','TOMMY','VIETNAM','123456789'),('2','TONY','VIETNAM','987654321'),
       ('3','TOMY','VIETNAM','1234567891'),('4','JOHNNY','VIETNAM','356112789'),
       ('6','KENNY','VIETNAM','1223236789')

INSERT INTO donhang 
VALUES ('1','LAPTOP ACER',100), ('2','LAPTOP ASUS',10),
       ('3','LAPTOP MSI',5), ('4','ZENPHONE ASUS',10),
       ('5','NOTEBOOK HP',10), ('6','IPHONE',10),
       ('7','MACBOOK PRO',10)
```

Here is the error I get. How can I fix it, and how about this errors with foreign key :( Please help, thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOtkQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing khachhang.KhachHangID on khachhang.KhachHangID

Values 
('5','NOTEBOOK HP',10)
('7','MACBOOK PRO',10)

do not match on khachhang table.

Comment: To be more specific, in order to Insert rows with a primary keys 5 and 7 into the [donhang] table, similar primary keys that equal 5 and 7 must **already exist** in the [khachhang] table.  This is the intended use of a foreign key relationship: you are not allowed to insert new values unless a similar value already exists in the other table.

Comment: I have fixed it here: INSERT INTO donhang values ('P11','LAPTOP ACER',100,1) but it show the error here : https://imgur.com/a/vRcf8fH